# pre_set_data and post_submit form event

Tags: php, symfony

I have two lists in my form : "State" and "Country". State list depends Country list.
I handle this with form events and according to the doc I need two events : pre_set_data and post_submit. So here my code im my Form type :

```
$formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Country $country) use ($options) {
// Query to get all states by countryID
}
```

1/ Initialisation

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier)
{
$country = ...;
$formModifier($event->getForm, $country);
}
```

2/ Post submit handler

```
$builder->get('country')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData());
}
```

Everything works fine except in case of form submit pre_set_data is called and post_submit too. My query in $formModifier function is called twice.

Is it the normal behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is normal. Both events occur, so both listeners are activated, calling your function $formModifier... so the function is called twice.

Comment: Fine but how can I do to avoid that ?